# Write a python script to calculate sum of following series :

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the sum of the series below but am not able to get the correct value of sum

`s = (1) + (1+2) + (1+2+n)`

I've used the following code

```
s = 0
n = int(input("Enter number : "))
for i in range (1,n+1):
        s  = s + 1 +i
print (s)
```

for n = 3 
the output should be 10

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to see where we can help you

Comment: added the code......

Answer (score 1):

After some analysis, it turns out there is a formula for that sum (you can simplify it further):

[image]

Coded:

```
def S(n):
  return (n + 1) * (4 * n ** 2 + 8 * n) // 24

print(S(3))
```

Output:

```
10
35
220
```

So your code becomes as follows (without a function):

```
n = int(input("Enter number : "))
s = (n + 1) * (4 * n ** 2 + 8 * n) // 24
print(s)
```

You can do it the hard way, without a formula (with loops):

```
s = 0
n = int(input("Enter number : "))
for i in range (1, n + 1):
  for j in range(1, i + 1):
    s = s + j
print(s)
```

Comment: @Saturn Of course, just use the formula directly (check the edit).

Comment: any other method because in our exam, I wouldn't have time to derive a formula for it ….. Thanks By the way

Comment: @Saturn In that case you can use two loops (nested loops).

Answer (score 1):

Without the formula, a shorter version of MrGreek's way

```
sum_=0 
n = 4
for i in range(n+1):
    sum_ = sum_ + sum(range(i+1))
print(sum_)
```